Properties of the de Rham complex for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
I wasn't able to find a construction of de Rham complex for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ using de Rham theorem. This is my attempt, in which I have some uncertainties.
Consider
$$
\Omega^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}\Omega^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}\Omega^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}\Omega^{3}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}\dots
$$
Modules of differential forms over the ring of smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Obviously $\Omega^{i\ge4} = 0$. Now, by de Rham theorem $H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R}) \simeq H^{i}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})$, and the latter are defined $H^{i}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R}) = \mathrm{Hom}(H_{i}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{R})$. Singular homologies of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are the same as for a point:
$$
H_{i}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R}) = H_{i}(\mathrm{pt},\mathbb{R}) = \begin{cases}\mathbb{R}, \quad \text{for  $i =0$}\\ 0, \quad \text{for $i\ge 1$}\end{cases}
$$
Thus the same holds for cohomology:
$$
H^{i}_{\mathrm{dR}}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R}) \simeq H^{i}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R}) = H_{i}(\mathrm{pt},\mathbb{R}) = \begin{cases}\mathbb{R}, \quad \text{for  $i =0$}\\ 0, \quad \text{for $i\ge 1$}\end{cases}
$$
By definition of $\mathrm{d}$:
$$
\forall f\in\Omega^{0}:\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\mathrm{d}x^{1} + \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x^{2} + \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x^{3}}\mathrm{d}x^{3}\\
\forall f_{1}\mathrm{d}x^{1} + f_{2}\mathrm{d} x^{2} + f_{3}\mathrm{d} x^{3} = \left(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x^{1}} - \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x^{2}}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} + \left(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x^{3}} - \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{1} + \left(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x^{1}} - \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x^{1}}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3}\\
\forall f_{1}\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{3} + f_{2}\mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{1} + f_{3}\mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} = \left(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x^{1}} + \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial f_{3}}{\partial x^{3}} \right)\mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{3}
$$
Which in local coordinates look exactly like $\nabla$, $\nabla\times$, $\nabla\cdot$ ($\mathrm{grad}$, $\mathrm{rot}$ or $\mathrm{curl}$, $\mathrm{div}$), however instead of acting from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ $\nabla\times$ acts from tangent bundle to its square.
First question, which I have: is it enough to mention the Poincare correspondence to refer to $\Omega^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}} \Omega^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})$ as a curl? Or is it some kind of an argument stating, that if it behaves like this locally, then it also works globally?
Second one: do I understand correctly that cohomologies give us such desired equalities as $\nabla\times(\nabla f) = 0$ and $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times(f_{1}\mathrm{d}x^{1} + f_{2}\mathrm{d} x^{2} + f_{3}\mathrm{d} x^{3})) = 0$ and the inverse statements like if $\nabla\times \omega$, then there is $f\in\Omega^{0}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{R})$ such that $\omega = \mathrm{d}f$?
Also I have a third optional question. Is there a connection between this business and gauge invariance in classical relativistic electro-magnetism theory? (Because it seems that the switch of gauge in terms of scalar and vector potentials is like switching between two elements of cohomology class of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.)
(Sorry if something of this is obvious or naively wrong, I just haven't found the sufficient resources and want some certainty and clarification). 

(1) The idea that $d \colon \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2$ acts "via the curl operator" can be made precise by using the Hodge star.  (2) The statement $\nabla \times (\nabla f) = 0$ is equivalent to $d^2 = 0$.  Because $d^2 = 0$, the cohomology groups are well-defined.  The fact that $H^1(\mathbb{R}^3) = 0$ is the converse statement.  (Note that on domains $U \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with $H^1(U) \neq 0$, the converse is false.) (3) Yes, there is a connection to gauge invariance in electromagnetic theory, but I'm not the best person to explain it.

@jesse-madnick thanks!

You’re missing $d$ in two of your definitions. :)

@TedShifrin can you, please, clarify where?
